# Unable use PooledRedisClientManager

Tags: redis, visual-studio-2015, servicestack

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 but am unable to resolve `PooledRedisClientManager` in AppHost. Can anybody tell what the problem is?

> ERROR :   The type or namespace name 'PooledRedisClientManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```cs
using ServiceStack;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using ServiceStack.Redis;
using Funq;

//APP HOST in Global.asax
public MyAppHost() : base("Services ", typeof(myServices).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "api" });
        container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(new PooledRedisClientManager());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [download ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#download) from NuGet:

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Redis
```